# What is the complete list of search terms in ROS index?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Help for index.ros.org brings up a generic lunrjs help page. But that assumes you know the available search terms. I discovered I can do, for example, "+distro:galactic +name:*gtest*" because I guessed the **distro** and **name** fields.  But surely there are others.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391064/what-is-the-complete-list-of-search-terms-in-ros-index?/) by [rkent](https://answers.ros.org/users/55154/rkent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2021-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @rkent, not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for, after some digging in the `rosindex` repo, I found this code for `rosindex_genarator.rb`, you can see a list under `package_info` and I believe these are the fields you are looking for:

Source: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosindex/blob/ros2/_plugins/rosindex_generator.rb#L517

```
  package_info = {
    'name' => package_name,
    'pkg_type' => pkg_type,
    'distro' => distro,
    'raw_uri' => raw_uri,
    'browse_uri' => browse_uri,
    'docs_uri' => docs_uri,
    # required package info
    'version' => version,
    'license' => license,
    'description' => description,
    'maintainers' => maintainers,
    # optional package info
    'authors' => authors,
    'urls' => urls,
    'ci_data' => ci_data,
    # dependencies
    'pkg_deps' => pkg_deps,
    'system_deps' => system_deps,
    'dependants' => {},
    # exports
    'deprecated' => deprecated,
    # rosindex metadata
    'tags' => tags,
    'nodes' => nodes,
    # readme
    'readmes' => readmes,
    # changelog
    'changelog' => changelog,
    'changelog_rendered' => changelog_rendered,
    # assets
    'launch_data' => launch_data,
    'plugin_data' => plugin_data,
    'msg_files' => msg_files.map {|f| Pathname.new(f).relative_path_from(local_package_path).to_s },
    'srv_files' => srv_files.map {|f| Pathname.new(f).relative_path_from(local_package_path).to_s },
    'wiki' => {'exists'=>false}
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rkent](https://answers.ros.org/users/55154/rkent/) on 2021-11-17**:
Yep that looks like it, thanks!